# Different oscillator indicators in the same pine script but plot them separately

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, technical-indicator

I wrote different oscillator indicators (such as RSI, SRSI, etc.) in the same pine script so that all can be plotted by loading a single script. However, all the indicators are being plotted together. I like to plot them separately. Is there any way to do this?

Below is a sample code. It plots them together.

```
indicator("RSI and SRSI", overlay=false)

// Input parameters
length = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length")
srsi_k = input.int(14, title="SRSI %K Length")
srsi_d = input.int(3, title="SRSI %D Smoothing")

// Calculate RSI
rsi = ta.rsi(close, length)

// Calculate SRSI
srsi = ta.stoch(rsi, rsi, rsi, srsi_k)
srsi_d_value = ta.sma(srsi, srsi_d)

// Plot RSI
plot(rsi, color=color.blue, title="RSI")

// Plot SRSI %K
plot(srsi, color=color.red, title="SRSI %K")

// Plot SRSI %D
plot(srsi_d_value, color=color.green, title="SRSI %D")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to plot two oscillators in different panes with a single Pine Script code.

However, since both RSI and Stochastic RSI are bounded oscillators (i.e., they range from 0 to 100), you can change the scale of one of them to do this.

Below, I added 100 to the Stochastic RSI and plotted a solid horizontal line using `hline()` to separate them. I also added over-bought and over-sold levels:
[image]

The code:

```
// @version=5
indicator("RSI and SRSI", overlay=false)

// Input parameters
length = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length")
srsi_k = input.int(14, title="SRSI %K Length")
srsi_d = input.int(3, title="SRSI %D Smoothing")

// Calculate RSI
rsi = ta.rsi(close, length)

// Calculate SRSI
srsi = ta.stoch(rsi, rsi, rsi, srsi_k)
srsi_d_value = ta.sma(srsi, srsi_d)

// Plot RSI
plot(rsi, color=color.blue, title="RSI")

// Plot RSI OB/OS Levels
rsi_h0 = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsi_h1 = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsi_h0, rsi_h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="RSI Background")

// Plot a solid separator line between the two oscillators
hline(100, "Separator", color.white, hline.style_solid)

// Plot SRSI %K
plot(srsi+100, color=color.red, title="SRSI %K")

// Plot SRSI %D
plot(srsi_d_value+100, color=color.green, title="SRSI %D")

// Plot SRSI OB/OS Levels
srsi_h0 = hline(180, "SRSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(150, "SRSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
srsi_h1 = hline(120, "SRSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(srsi_h0, srsi_h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="SRSI Background")
```

Comment: Thank you. Mark this answer as the solution if it helped solve your issue.